# Ques regarding sending email to a specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I just googled n found out this code:-

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage            ("abc@somedomain.com","administrator@anotherdomain.com","Testing","This is a test mail");
```

Now my ques:-
How do I send a nicely formatted Email with links and all instead of  simple text "This is a test mail" ??
I don't wanna attach no file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could send the message body as HTML which will allow you to have links and such:

```
var message = new MailMessage("abc@somedomain.com", "administrator@anotherdomain.com");
message.Subject = "Testing";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "<html><body><div>Test message</div><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">some link</a></body></html>";
```